# C# WPF Authorization System

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I am looking to add an authorization type system to my new program but have no idea how to go about this. Basically what I am wanting to do is either prompt a user for an authorization code or have a textbox on the gui for them to enter an authorization code.

This authorization code should be required prior to the user being able to run a function and be generated by an admin (me). I have no problem restricting the function but do not have the slightest clue if a system already exists that I can implement or if some sort of math logic should be used. Ex: Authorization code minus some value is equal to a value then approve key.

Any advice or help on this subject would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

How concerned are you about security? Easiest way is...

1. Hard code authorization constant into the application (or get it from a database..).
2. Prompt user with dialog box on application load.
3. Do not go further until user enters in matching code.

Comment: I am not super concerned on security where I am going to run a DB for this, I just want something a normal user wont figure out by saying hey its just increments of 10. Maybe a hard code saying value divided by something is equal to 1.5? Your suggestion?

Comment: Something like the first part of a GUID should work... such as DF2A0F2C. I don't see any reason to obfuscate it with mathematics unless you want to generate unique keys per user.